# Marshallian demand from indirect function - trouble with derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, economics

This is an microeconomics question, and I'm having trouble with the derivative of an integral function. The question is as follows:

From the following indirect-utility function, obtain the marshallian demand for x.

$V(p,b) =  G\left(A(p) + \frac{\bar{b}^\eta b^{1 - \eta}}{1-\eta} \right)$

Where $ A(p) = \int_{p}^{p^G} x(\epsilon,\bar{b})d\epsilon$

So I went through Roy's Identity: $- x(p,b) = \frac{\partial v /\partial p}{\partial v / \partial b}$

$\partial v(p,b)/ \partial b = G'(.) \bar{b}^\eta b^{-\eta}$

$\partial v(p,b)/ \partial p = G'(.) \frac{\partial A(p)}{\partial p} $

The $G'()s$ will cancel out , but I'm having trouble with $ \frac{\partial A(p)}{\partial p} $

I tried applying the first theorem of calculus as this: $ \int_{p}^{p^G} x(\epsilon,\bar{b})d\epsilon = F(x(p^G,\bar{b})) - F(x(p,\bar{b}) $

From this I got $ \frac{\partial A(p)}{\partial p} = G p^{G-1} x(p^G,\bar{b}) - x(p,\bar{b}) $.

But ending up with two different price vectors ($ x(p,\bar{b})$ and $ x(p^g,\bar{b} $)) on x don't look like it's the way to go.

Any input would be greatly appreciated on how to handle $ \frac{\partial A(p)}{\partial p} $

### Thanks!

Comment on mlc's hint: seems i'm misapplying Leibniz' rule: I'm getting:
$ \frac{x(p^g,\bar{b})(p^G)' - x(p,\bar{b})*p'}{\partial p}$

Comment: Hint: use Leibniz's rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under appropriate conditions, (a simplified version of) the Leibniz's rule states
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) dt = f(x,b(x)) b^\prime(x) - f(x,a(x)) a^\prime(x)$$

Apply this rule to 
$$A(p) = \int_{p}^{p^G} x(\epsilon,\bar{b})d\epsilon$$
and obtain
$$\frac{d}{dp} A(p) = - x(p,\bar{b})$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, mlc. 
Would you mind expanding (applying) the rule to A(p), before the derivative ? 
I'm misinterpreting the rule, as I end up getting:
$x(p^g,\bar{b}) p^G' - x(p,\bar{b})*p'$ .

Where does the first part go?

Comment: @Flek: I did the work assuming that $p$ and $p^G$ are two different variables, and you only seek the derivative wrt $p$.